# How to disable Chrome JavaScript console re-evaluation of arrays and objects?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I was wondering if there was some way to disable the re-evaluation of an object/array in the Chrome developer console?

**Example:**

```
// Array to be displayed
const my_array = [5, 6, 7, 8];
console.log(my_array);

// Change the array
my_array.push(9);
console.log(my_array);

// What is displayed in console
my_array: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
my_array: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I have been circumventing this by using `JSON.stringify()` (which can be put inside a function such as `log(message)`), but it gets obnoxious to always have to use it.

I'm guessing it is using references to the arrays and objects which, on update of the arrays/objects, updates the log.

Is there a setting or an extension or some other feature that can stop Chrome from re-evaluating everything real-time?